# JSON localstrorage | based on Raymond Camden RSS viewer

Tags: json, jsonp, local-storage

I try to reproduce [Raymond Camden Rss Viewer](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/24/PhoneGap-RSS-Reader--Part-3), except I'm using a JSON feed instead of regular RSS xml feed.

When feed is ok, use  localStorage to store entries.

Please, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/elektrorl/QQhU7/

Why I'm i getting only one entry, and this one is near the end of the list. Why only this one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from Raymon Camden himself; it solves the topic:

"This line:

```
entries = [];
```

is inside your each loop, which means the array is getting destroyed each time. Move it to before the each loop."